# How to define IP and hostname of another PC in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, hostname

in Mac or Linux, we can simply define IP and hostname in `/etc/hosts`. Then we can call another local computer with hostname (not with IP) we defined. But in windows, How can I do that? Where can I edit such configuration?

Answer (score 8):

The hosts file in Windows can be found at

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

this is typically:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

The format in Windows is the same as in Linux.

Comment: +1 - 26 seconds earlier?  That means it took me 26 seconds to write my answer too.  Don't you just love how realtime SO is.  It rocks.

Comment: @Andras: Only for trivial questions. Anything remotely complicated can take hours or days or gather no good answers at all.